# How to send "Cache-Control: no-cache" header in Piwik API responses

Tags: http, http-headers, matomo

I have a Piwik install sitting behind a varnish-caching server. My problem is varnish is by default caching responses to my API calls. Unfortunately, I don't have direct access to the varnish server, so I need to send the

```
"Cache-Control: no-cache"
```

header with my API responses. Is there a setting or a way to modify my piwik install to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to `.htaccess` in your piwik install, `core/API/` folder:

```
<Files Request.php>
  Header set Cache-Control "no-cache"
</Files>
```

If you need to add the header to other URLs, follow the same pattern.

Note that Piwik already adds `Cache-Control: max-age=0` to these responses, so if that's not working for you on the Request.php path you probably want to add this to .htaccess in the folder with `piwik.js` (root of piwik install) as well:

```
<Files piwik.php>
  Header set Cache-Control "no-cache"
</Files>
```